# Password protecting shell access

Tags: adb, shell

We distribute android devices to other developers so that they can develop on our devices. We want them to be able to install / uninstall / debug apps, but we don't want them to be able to run `adb shell` and look around in the file system. Our devices are rooted. Is it possible?

Comment: If they would be able to install apps, what would stop them from using those apps  to peek into your filesystem directly or through a local shell? I don't think I understand what you really want. If there are certain files you don't want them to see, encrypt them perhaps?

Comment: This is hypothetical but removing user 2000 from sdcard_rw and sdcard_r groups should help. Android doesn't have the in-built tools to remove a user from a group and I can't seem to find third-party ones either.

Comment: @Firelord well yes the point would also be to block any app to peek into the filesystem

Comment: Simply not possible with root access. Without root there can be some workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

It might be possible by modifying **su**  source code. You can modify so that some commands require a password such as the shell. Create your own custom su based on the device.

Comment: Hi! We tend to invite answers which work or are useful, not just speculative because that doesn't  help much. Moreover, this is just a pointer (and that too for development, something end-users can't afford) and not exactly an answer. And, when there is a bounty more efforts are expected from an answerer than usual.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. Users have root access, they can place a different shell binary at different location, and can even use a different `su` binary.